# Spring-Boot: Error injection multiple beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get an application working in Spring-boot, but I'm running into injections errors.   I have a @Service with a few @Autowire Classes. The classes our just POJO with a `public setDatSource` method that I need to set the DataSource via runtime.  See below:

```java
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("datasetDao")
    public com.lexi.dao.core.DatasetDAO getDatasetDao() throws NamingException {
        DatasetDAOImpl ds = new DatasetDAOImpl();
        ds.setDataSource(createAuthReadDataSoure());

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LicenseDAO getLicenseDao() throws NamingException {
        LicenseDAOImpl ds = new LicenseDAOImpl();
        ds.setReadDataSource(createOnlineDSReadDataSoure());
        ds.setWriteDataSource(createOnlineDSWriteDataSoure());
        ds.setDistribDataSource(createAuthReadDataSoure());

        return ds;
    }
```

I have a Service define as this:

```java
@Service
public class LicenseService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasetDao")
    private DatasetDAO datasetDao;

    @Autowired
    private LicenseDAO licenseDao;
```

However when I run the application I get this:

```sh
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field datasetDao in com.wk.online.services.LicenseService required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - createAuthReadDataSoure: defined by method 'createAuthReadDataSoure' in com.wk.online.ws.OnlineWsApplication
    - createOnlineDSReadDataSoure: defined by method 'createOnlineDSReadDataSoure' in com.wk.online.ws.OnlineWsApplication
    - createOnlineDSWriteDataSoure: defined by method 'createOnlineDSWriteDataSoure' in com.wk.online.ws.OnlineWsApplication


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I tried to add a @Qualifier but that didn't seem to jive wiht Spring.  What am I missing, I been at this for a while and figured i'm doing something very stupid.

Comment: Could you add code for these 3 methods : createAuthReadDataSoure, createOnlineDSReadDataSoure, createOnlineDSWriteDataSoure ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `@Bean` annotation on following methods in `OnlineWsApplication` class?

- `createAuthReadDataSoure`
- `createOnlineDSReadDataSoure`
- `createOnlineDSWriteDataSoure`

If yes get rid of them.

Full code of `OnlineWsApplication` would be very useful to invastigate it.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue.  I must have been a long day since it wasn't obvious and I didn't see that.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

When defining the bean, you need to specify name, not qualifier, qualifier annotation should be used where you autowire it:

```
@Bean(name = "datasetDao")
public com.lexi.dao.core.DatasetDAO getDatasetDao() throws NamingException {
    DatasetDAOImpl ds = new DatasetDAOImpl();
    ds.setDataSource(createAuthReadDataSoure());

    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the bean definition, instead of 
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("datasetDao")

Try using the following:
    @Bean(name="datasetDao")